# Is there a word specifically for "a transitive/intransitive verb pair"?

Tags: grammar, transitivity, linguistics

There are many pairs of transitive and intransitive verbs in Japanese: e.g. 上げる and 上がる, 交える and 交じる, 広げる and 広がる.

Separately, transitive verbs are called 他動詞{たどうし} and intransitive verbs are called 自動詞{じどうし}.

So is there a single term which refers to one of these pairs of transitive and intransitive verbs? That is, what is the linguistic term, in Japanese, for a pairing such as 上げる/上がる?

Comment: Do you want the equivalent of "transitivity" or "transitive-intransitive pair"?

Comment: There is this term 自他の対応 but it refers to a correspondence between an intransitive verb and a transitive verb, not a pair.

Comment: @naruto the latter

Comment: @aguijonazo thank you, this is pretty close. I did some digging based on this and found the phrase 「自・他対応」 which may be what I'm looking for?

Comment: 対応 means correspondence. To refer to a concrete pair like 上がる and 上げる you would need to say something like 自・他のペア.

Comment: How about 有対動詞(paired verbs)？

Comment: FYI [有対自他動詞](http://webnotepage.a.la9.jp/kajeroj1/_tbKwrlR.html). But I guess it is more understandable to use ペア like 自他のペア.